# Order prices according to currency

Tags: mysql

I need to order prices, but it has currencies, so it's not so easy as it looks. The table:

```
lowmoney | topmoney | currency

1 | 99 | eur
2 | 59 | usd
```

The above example means that the prices are 1.99EUR and 2.59$ . There are ~5000 entries and I need to order it by actual price, for example 1.99EUR is more than 2.19$, so

```
ORDER BY lowmoney DESC, topmoney DESC
```

doesn't work.

P.S. There are two currencies only - usd and eur.

Comment: The SQL db has no concept of the conversion rate between the two, you will need to return all results and do this outside of the query.

Comment: This is not possible, the SQL database would require some source of conversion rates which change constantly. So you have to do this yourself.

Comment: this will be calculated with currency change rate

Comment: You should do your sorting at the presentation layer instead, since that's likely where you're performing the currency conversion. Alternatively, create a new column to house the exchange rate, and periodically update that column through a scheduled task. Then you can perform everything you need in your TSQL.

Comment: If you really want to do it at DB you could write a function that converts euros to dollars (or the opposite) be sure to pass a parameter to know whether is dollar or euro, so you don't do unnecessary conversions. The idea is to choose once currency and convert the other one to it, then order by the new generated column. Keep in mind that the conversion rate will be hardcoded, so it won't be accurrate but depending on what you need, it might suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select
  lowmoney,
  topmoney,
  currency
from TheTable
order by
  /* Order by amount in dollars (could calculate to euro as well) */
  (lowmoney + (topmoney / 100)) *
  case currency 
    when 'eur' then 1.3266 /* Current exchange rate, according to Google */
    when 'usd' then 1
  else
    null /* What to do with other currencies. */
  end desc
```

Answer (score 1):

say you have : `1 US dollar` is worth `0.7618 Euro`

then

use this

```
select concat(`lowmoney`,',', `topmoney`)as money,currency,
       case when `currency` = 'eur' then concat(lowmoney,',' ,topmoney) 
            when `currency` = 'usd' then concat(lowmoney,',' ,topmoney) *  0.7618
            end as money_in_euro  
 from table2
 order by money_in_euro asc
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05f3f/9)

output:

```
   MONEY    CURRENCY    MONEY_IN_EURO
   1,99       eur            1,99
   2,59       usd            1.5236
```

> - if you have other currencies just add WHEN currency = 'gdgd' then concat(...) * the_rate